# How to highlight a specific word in a searched content in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, regex, wordpress

I want to highlight the search term in the content result in WordPress.

I tried some functions for title, excerpt and content highlight. Title and excerpt working fine but in content its not working fine. it disturb my content layout.

My actual layout is 
[image]

And after using function for highlight search term in content. It looks like this

[image]

The function which i use title highlight is

```
function search_title() {
$title = get_the_title();
$keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
$content = strip_tags($content);
$title = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<strong class="search-highlight">\0</strong>', $title);
echo $title;
```

}

And the function which i use for content is

```
function search_content() {
    $content = get_the_content();
    $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
    // $content = strip_tags($content);
    $content = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<strong class="search-highlight">\0</strong>', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('~(?:\[/?)[^/\]]+/?\]~s', '', $content);
    echo '<p>' . $content . '</p>';
```

}

Its working fine but break my layout.

I tried some of the jquery methods too. but no luck.

Comment: For a jQuery solution have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shaban try this code your search.php and remove **search_content()** from functions.php

Get the search term by this code.

```
<?php echo $str = esc_html( get_search_query( false ) ); ?>
```

and then write jquery in same file with **contains:** function. like this

```
$( ".content-column:contains('<?php echo $str ?>')" ).css( "background", "Yellow" );
```

That's it :)

Hope this will help you